# What is the java equivalent for the SHA1 hash that is produced in .Net?

Tags: java, .net, character-encoding

Am trying to authenticate a soap webservice, but the SHA1 hash that I produce in java is not working but the hash produced with .Net works.

What is the java equivalent for this .Net code?

//.Net

```
var token = "H?OIgSJ35~LKJ:9~~7&sUtHDeKAv*O@is?cEwV[}!i@u%}";
var shaProvider = new SHA1Managed();
var rawKey = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(token);
var rawHash = shaProvider.ComputeHash(rawKey);
var signature = BitConverter.ToString(rawHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

Hash produced:a508a29efeea2821e519fcbf64f164dd5d672233

//Java - This is what I tried using commons-codec-1.4.jar

```
String token = "H?OIgSJ35~LKJ:9~~7&sUtHDeKAv*O@is?cEwV[}!i@u%}";
MessageDigest cript = null;
try {
    cript = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
cript.reset();
cript.update(token.getBytes());
String password = new String(Hex.encodeHex(cript.digest()));
System.out.println(password);
```

Hash produced:88e7c8fc13ac75e8efc8d0c00182caa6dc087093

Comment: What strings do those respective blocks produce?

Comment: It seems `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` has different encoding than `String.getBytes`. Have you tried comparing those two outputs? Try `token.getBytes("UTF-16LE")`.

Comment: @alberge, have added those in my edit

Comment: @Mohan Compare the outputs of `getBytes` and `GetBytes`. That's most likelly where the differences appear. Maybe you need to add BOM character. I'm not sure if .NET adds it.

Comment: FWIW, I get `f230595bf9db04d36fc2b63f824cd35635aa7468` as the hash of that token. Tested using both Python and `sha1sum`. Can you reproduce the sample hashes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Example_hashes

Comment: @Banthar, token.getBytes("UTF-16LE") works fine thanks.

Comment: @algerge I used the samples from wiki to find the solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `token.getBytes()` doesn't use the same encoding as `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(token)`, since you're unlikely to have UTF-16 Little Endian as your default charset. What happens if you change it to `token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)`?

Comment: Where can I find StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE? I can find one in rt.jar, it is sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets but doesn't have UTF_16LE

Comment: @Mohan [java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)

Comment: @Banthar thanks for the reply, but I couldn't find that in rt.jar. Whats the jar that contains it?

Comment: @Mohan Sorry. I somehow lost the important part of the comment. As the link says it was introduced in java 1.7. You probably have older version. But, as far as I know, it should behave exactly as `getBytes("UTF-16LE")`.